# Universe Simulation for Creating Inventions

Tags: simulation

Hi I am looking for software that can help me develop constructions that will work in real life. A lot of the time in real life I can't buy all the tools/materials necessary to do so or have the space to store such things.

For example:

- I'd like to experiment with magnets and wires to create my own generators
- I'd like to construct complicated objects like cars that actually "work"

  - That means I need to be able to create a working engine for the car so I need to be able to build the cylinders and so on, so it would need to be able to support all the physics that go along with it.
- The shape of an object could be designed in another program and brought into the program - and then you would give it all the properties.

  - Design a horse-shoe magnet in a program which is made for designing 3d objects

    - Import it into this program, and define what type of material it is made from and then the magnetic fields are automatically generated from it.

Does anyone know of any projects which are working towards this goal? When I type in "real life simulator" I get games which are not related to this idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that if this kind of simulator existed, you would have already heard about it.